# Error in displaying date

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2

In my MVC2 application, I want to display date in tabular form as 5/31/2013 but what i get is 5/31/2013 12:00:00 AM
my controller code is :

```
public ActionResult MyAccount()
    {
        var user = User.Identity.Name;
       System.Data.DataTable dt = new System.Data.DataTable();
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        string qry = "select * from Info where UserName= '" + user + "'";
        open_Connection();
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(qry, conn);
        da.Fill(ds);
        dt = ds.Tables[0];
        foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
        {
            tableInfo.Add(new TableInfo() { FileName = row[1].ToString(), Date = row[3].ToString() , Time = row[4].ToString(), Info = row[5].ToString() });
        }
        close_Connection();
        return View(tableInfo);
    }
```

Model:

```
public class TableInfo
{
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string FileName { get; set; }
    public string Date { get; set; }
    public string Time { get; set; }  
    public string Info { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Use `SELECT CONVERT(varchar(10), GETDATE(), 101)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your TableInfo model, add this attribute above the Date:

```
[DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:d}")]
public string Date { get; set; }
```

The {0:d} part is the short date format identifier.. You can also customize it like {0:dd-MM-yyyy}.

Or you could just convert the retrieved date by:

```
Date = DateTime.Parse(row[3].ToString()).ToShortDateString()
```

Or

```
Date = row[3].ToString("{0:d}")
```